# Pass java.util.Date using as @Param in query method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have used java.util.Date attribute in query method in spring boot repository. But it giving me "**Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param java.util.Date for value '2014-11-27"**  error. I have mentioned code segments the Entity class and Repository class below. What would be the problem here ?

Entity Class

```
@Column(name="date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```

Repository

```
public interface WeatherRepository extends CrudRepository<Weather, String> {
List<Weather> findAllByDate(@Param("date") Date date);
Weather findWeatherByCity(@Param("city") String city);
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling the findAllByDate() ?

Comment: I gonna call it form the url http://localhost:8080/weathers/findAllByDate?date="09-08-2015"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try sending the date in this format - ***11/27/2014 (MM/dd/yyyy)***. This should be able to parse it from the request URI in this format. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation on the `date` parameter to specify the format explicitly. In the annotation, you can use either the

- `pattern` to specify an arbitrary pattern (following the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns)
- `iso` to use one of the standard ISO formats
- `style` for a shorthand two-letter code for date and time formats (**S**hort/ **M**edium/**L**ong/**F**ull/**-**)

Choose only one of the configuration options.

Then you can use any of `Date`, `Calendar`, `Long`, Joda-Time types or (Spring 4 + JDK 8) `java.time` types as your parameter type.